# Oracle SQL LAG() function results in duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very simple query that results in two rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
id,
trunc(start_date) start_date
FROM   example.table
WHERE ID = 1
```

This results in the following rows:

```
id    start_date
1     7/1/2012
1     9/1/2016
```

I want to add a column that simply shows the previous date for each row. So I'm using the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                Trunc(start_date) start_date,
                Lag(start_date, 1)
                  over (
                    ORDER BY start_date) pdate
FROM   example.table
WHERE  id = 1
```

However, when I do this, I get four rows instead of two:

```
id    start_date    pdate
1     7/1/2012      NULL
1     7/1/2012      7/1/2012
1     9/1/2016      7/1/2012
1     9/1/2016      9/1/2012
```

If I change the offset to 2 or 3 the results remain the same. If I change the offset to 0, I get two rows again but of course now the start_date == pdate.

I can't figure out what's going on

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT id, trunc(start_date) as start_date,
       LAG(trunc(start_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY trunc(start_date))
FROM   example.table
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY id, trunc(start_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is: the order of execution of an SQL statements, is that `LAG` runs *before* the `DISTINCT`.

You actually want to run the `LAG` **after** the `DISTINCT`, so the right query should be:

```
WITH t1 AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT id, trunc(start_date) start_date
   FROM   example.table
   WHERE ID = 1
)
SELECT *, LAG(start_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) pdate
FROM   t1
```